# c# testing a webMethod using IQueryable works but does not after publishing

Tags: c#, .net

I have developed web services using c# for a while now. And everything up till now worked fine, but today even though while debugging the code runs fine like it has been for few months now but when i publish the code and put it on a IIS it gives  and error.

the message is:

```
The type or namespace name 'AKAB_Item_AKItem' could not be found
```

the code which works while debugging but crashes when published.

```
 IQueryable<KAB_Item_AKItem> akitemsswe = null;
            if (date_last_modified != null)
            {
                akitemsswe = from result in dc2.AKAB_Item_AKItems
                             where result.Last_Date_Modified > DateTime.ParseExact(date_last_modified.ToString(), "dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm:ss", null)
                             select result;
            }
            else
            {
                akitemsswe = from result in dc2.AKAB_Item_AKItems
                             select result;
            }
```

Am I missing something because i can not wrap my head around that the debugging works but the published project does not.

Comment: Are you sure that the assembly which contains type `AKAB_Item_AKItem` is also copied while publishing the Web Service?

Comment: Positive. Even opened the files in the server diretcory with notepad and saw that it is there.